# How do I create stylesheet for multiple table styles when they can each appear inside each other?

Tags: css

I have 4 different table styles as follows:

```
table {
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(166, 201, 226);
}

table th {
    background-color:navy;
    padding: 4px, 5px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(166, 201, 226);
    vertical-align: middle;
}

table td {
    padding: 4px, 5px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(166, 201, 226);
    vertical-align: middle;
}


/* Invisible - no borders, no table margin */
table.invisible {
    margin: 0px;
    border: 0px;
}

table.invisible td {
    border: 0px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

/* Invisible: Middle Align */
table.invisible-middlealign {
    margin: 0px;
    border: 0px;
}

table.invisible-middlealign td {
    border: 0px;
}

/* Invisible: Middle Align - No Pad */
table.invisible-middlealignnopad {
    margin: 0px;
    border: 0px;
}

table.invisible-middlealignnopad td {
    border: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

/* Invisible: No Pad */
table.invisible-nopadding {
    border: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

table.invisible-nopadding td {
    border: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Sometimes I am finding that for example I need an 'invisible' table inside a 'invisible-middlealignnopad' table but on another occasion the 'invisible-middlealignnopad' table needs to be inside the 'invisible' one. Given the different combinations I can have, the only way I have catered for this is by doing something like the following:

```
table.invisible td table.invisible-middlealignnopad td {
    border: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

I then have to replicate this for all combinations.

I'm guessing that there's got to be a better/standard way of handling this requirement. Appreciate any suggestions :)

Thanks,
Neil

Comment: Could it be as simple as making a "no-pad" class that has !important; that you then add into the HTML?  Can you add to the HTML or is it all dynamic?

Comment: @Michael I did think of that, but !important will override regardless of whether the important style is the inner or outer table. I have control over the html but am keen to only reference classes and not use inline... or am i missing what you're saying. A separate 'nopad' class - i.e. an additional one to what I already have?

Comment: Correct, in fact, it could be done without the !important class.  See my answer below for more detailed response.

Answer (score 0):

Could you simply create a class that you add to the HTML to control these certain things that need to be "overwritten" so to speak?  For example...

### CSS

Change your above CSS to the below...  If I am following your CSS correctly you need to account for times when a table should have no margin and no border, when a tables TD should have no padding and no border, and when a td should be aligntop or align middle.  In the below CSS, you can control the tables margin and border, td's padding and border and td's vertical alignment by adding classes to the tables appropriately.

Basically..  You are using HTML classes to override things, instead of using complex CSS selectors to override.  The overrides are more granular and controlled by your HTML.

```
table {
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(166, 201, 226);
}

table th {
    background-color:navy;
    padding: 4px, 5px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(166, 201, 226);
    vertical-align: middle;
}

table td {
    padding: 4px, 5px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(166, 201, 226);
    vertical-align: middle;
}

table.no-margin {
    margin: 0px;
    border: 0px;
}

table.no-padding td {
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
}

table.align-top td {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

### HTML

```
<table>
   <td>
      <table class="no-pad-border">
         <td>
            Something
         </td>
      </table>
   </td>
</table>
```

Comment: How would that would work if I in another place wanted the 'invisible' table inside the 'invisible-middlealign no-pad-border'? Relying on the order falls down then?

Comment: I guess what I'm after is a way of ensuring that the style of the inner table *always* overrides the style of the outer table, without having to specify every combination of inner and outer tables in my style sheet

Comment: @NeilRichards - I guess what I am getting at is that because you have different possibilities of nesting, you either need to do what you were originally doing which is a lot of work and a lot of extra code.  Or you need to segment things.  Make a class called table-border, and include that class only on tables that should have a border in your HTML.  Utilize multiple classes to cut down on CSS complexity.

Comment: @NeilRichards I edited my answer further, by segmenting your CSS styling into separate CSS classes you can then be more granular in your overrides without tons of extra css, you only add some simple class names in the HTML.  This would support any combination of invisible, visible, middealign, topalign that you could possibly want.

Comment: I have made things more granular as you suggested and that does reduce some of the complexity. However I still have to specify hierarchical styles (as per my original 2nd block of code), as without it html that has a table (with no class) containing a table.no-padding - using your examples, the cells in the no-padding table will inherit the style from the default specification, not the no-padding specification